# Identical code compiled in MCUXpresso is 3 times larger than in MDK-ARM … Why?

Tags: arm, embedded, keil, nxp-microcontroller

I ported an old project targeting LPC1788, not even all of the code.

Size summary in Keil says:

*Program Size: Code=158,812 RO-data=195,200 RW-data=1,130,632 ZI-data=36424*

Adding together:
Code + data = 354012 bytes of 524288 (0x80000) = 67.5% used

In MCUXpresso:

Memory region | Used Size | Region Size | %age Used

```
 ER_ROM1:     829308 B    512 KB     158.18%
```

For example, per .map file, this function:

```
void init_lcd(void)
{
    reset_lcd (FALSE); 
    toggle_frame_flg = FALSE;
}
```

Compiles into 16 bytes of code in MDK-ARM vs. 24 bytes of code in MCUXpresso.

Could this be related to floating point?

I noticed the following phenomena – changing this line:
`SEC_DELAY (1.0f / (float)poll_rate);`

To this one:
`SEC_DELAY (1 / poll_rate);`

Reduces used the size in MCUXpresso by 1,300 bytes!

I'm using Newlib-Nano in MCUXpresso and no optimization in both parties. Following other suggestions, I tried "-mfloat-abi=softfp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections" linker flags to no avail.

Is there any way to resolve or investigate further? I’m a beginner and something fairly obvious to experienced developers isn't that clear to me.

Thank you,

Eugene

**Edited 04/15/2023:**

In my attempt to keep the message short, I missed few important details; here they are:

Port: From Keil 5 to MCUXpresso, via these steps:

1. Created new C project.
2. Described all memory sections in “Managed Linker Script” in “Settings” dialog, making sure they match Keil scatter file.
3. Called “main()” explicitly from “cr_startup_lpc177x_8x.c”
4. Copied all files from uVision project, except those few that handle SD card; commented all SD card-related includes and invocations out.

That did it – the project compiles, but won’t fit into the flash.

**ARMCC compiler switches:**
-c --cpu Cortex-M3 -O0 -Otime --apcs=interwork --split_sections --asm --interleave --asm_dir ".\Output\"
-IC:/Keil_v5/ARM/RV31/INC
-IC:/Keil_v5/ARM/CMSIS/Include
-IC:/Keil_v5/ARM/INC/NXP/LPC177x_8x
-D__UVISION_VERSION="537" -DDEBUG -DxxxLOG
-o .\Output*.o --list_dir ".\Output\" --list --omf_browse .\Output*.crf --depend .\Output*.d

**Linker:**
--cpu Cortex-M3 *.o
--nodebug --strict --scatter ".\xxx_ARM.sct"
--pad=0xFF --callgraph --summary_stderr --info summarysizes --map --xref --callgraph --symbols
--info sizes --info totals --info unused --info veneers
--list ".\Output\XXXVX_XX.map"
-o .\Output\XXXVX_XX.axf

**GCC compiler switches:**
-std=c17 -DDEBUG -D__NEWLIB__ -I"E:<path>\Include" -O0 -fno-common -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fno-builtin -mfloat-abi=softfp -fmerge-constants -fmacro-prefix-map="$(<D)/"= -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -D__NEWLIB__ -fstack-usage -specs=nano.specs

**Linker:**
-nostdlib -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -Xlinker -Map="XXX.map" -Xlinker --cref -Xlinker --gc-sections -Xlinker -print-memory-usage -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -T XXXX_Debug.ld

If optimization is turned ON in MCUXpresso, the used size drops to 816336B - still too large.

**As a beginner, it’s first time I heard about “thumb” vs. “full sized arm”.** Now that you mentioned it, I researched the Internet sources about this matter, then looked at the .map files:

**MDK-ARM:** every user function is marked as “Thumb Code” and their addresses are NOT 4-byte aligned:

> init_lcd    0x0001669d     **Thumb Code**    16   lcd.o(i.init_lcd)

**Ld:** library-based functions appear to be linked with the “…/arm-none-eabi/lib/**thumb**/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a” library, but the user functions are NOT the thumb code; the addresses of user functions are 4-byte aligned:

> .text          0x00002f24        0xcc8      ./Source/lcd.o
>
> ```
>             0x00002f70                  init_lcd
> ```

**I wonder if this IS the core of my problem.**
How do I set GCC to generate “thumb code”? I noticed “-mthumb” option is present, “Thumb mode” option is checked in ‘Settings” and grayed out in both, compiler and linker pages.

**Edited 04/20/2023**

As I continued investigating the issue, I disassembled “**lcd.o**” and compared the contents of “**init_lcd**” function in both, MDK-ARM:

```
                  init_lcd PROC
;;;68     /************************************************/
;;;69     void init_lcd(void)
000000  b510              PUSH     {r4,lr}
;;;70     {                                                                             
;;;71       reset_lcd (FALSE); 
000002  2000              MOVS     r0,#0
000004  f7fffffe          BL       reset_lcd
;;;72       toggle_frame_flg = FALSE;
000008  2000              MOVS     r0,#0
00000a  4901              LDR      r1,|L16.16|
00000c  7008              STRB     r0,[r1,#0]
;;;73       
;;;74     }                                                                             
00000e  bd10              POP      {r4,pc}
;;;75     
                          ENDP

                  |L16.16|
                          DCD      toggle_frame_flg
```

and its counterpart in GCC:

```
0000004c <init_lcd>:
  4c:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
  4e:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
  50:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  52:   f7ff fffe   bl  64 <reset_lcd>
            52: R_ARM_THM_CALL  reset_lcd
  56:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (60 <init_lcd+0x14>)
  58:   2200        movs    r2, #0
  5a:   701a        strb    r2, [r3, #0]
  5c:   bf00        nop
  5e:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
  60:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
            60: R_ARM_ABS32 toggle_frame_flg
```

The two instructions in the latter listing are missing from the former one - "add" at 4e and "nop" at 5c. Although I’m doubtful that just 4 bytes per function can make up almost 300KB in size difference, can anybody comment what may be the reason, please.

Thank you!

Eugene

Comment: `(1 / poll_rate)` is `0`, which I doubt is what you want. You might have to disassemble a function or two and compare. You might also want to look at the build logs and see how the compiler and linker are being invoked for each.

Comment: look at the disassembly.  no reason to expect any two compilers even for the same target to produce the same results.   are you building primarily for thumb on the 1788 or full sized arm? (instantly making the binary much larger)   floating point is definitely going to bloat the binary as is a C library.

Comment: no optimization?  well you can easily solve that.  why would you not optimize?  is this mission critical?

Comment: The need for floating point support in both cases would be the same, so while software floating point adds an overhead, that is not the reason for the difference in size.  Besides what you have observed is the overhead if introducing FP, subsequent FP operations will not have that overhead because it is shared code for all similar operations.

Comment: @old_timer LPC1788 is a Cortex-M3 device, so only supports Thumb2. However it is not clear if this "port" is from some other device or merely porting from one toolchain to another.  It is also not clear whether the port is to or from MCUXpresso.  If porting to ARM-MDK, there is no problem to resolve.  Perhaps there is a reason Xpresso is _free_ ;-)

Comment: @Eugene You need to clarify the nature of the "port".  Is this a change of target MCU, or a change of toolchain, or both?  What are you porting from/to?

Comment: @Clifford, oh yeah, was thinking arm7tdmi, but cortex-m3, the ISA is not the problem.  but yes the definition of port, and not looking at the output of the tools...

Comment: is the application not optimized or application and C library?   in both cases?  or was one linked with an optimized library and the other with an unoptimized library?

Comment: Don't get hung up on the "thumb" thing.  Cortex-M devices are Thumb2 _only_ you have no choice in that.  Also do not get confused by ARM's arcane numbering architecture vs core.  Cortex-M3 is ARMv7-M, while ARM7TDMI is ARMv4T while ARM7EJ, ARM9E and ARM10E cores are all ARMv5TE.

Comment: ARM-MDK v5.37 provided both ARM Compilers v5 and v6.  You mentioned ARMCC, but can you confirm that this is v5?

Comment: You said you had applied _no optimisation_.  But `-Otime` _is_ an optimisation.  Answer updated in the light of that revelation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

MCUXpresso uses GCC while Keil uses either ARMCC (ARM Compiler v5 or earlier) or LLVM/clang (since ARM Compiler V6).  Moreover Keil provides a choice of C libraries, the full library and "microlib", neither of which are Newlib based.  Another difference is Keil uses armlink while NXPXpresso uses ld from binutils.

So three very different toolchains, so you would not expect them to generate the same code, or even similar code sizes.

In a device without hardware floating point, a single floating point operation in your code will pull in a whole lot of code to support it, but it is a one time hit, further floating point operations of the same kind will have far less impact in the code.  Trivial use of FP is best avoided in embedded systems, and is usually easily avoided.  For example you might implement an integer delay that works in say milliseconds rather than seconds:

```
MILLISEC_DELAY (1000u / poll_rate) ;
```

The fact that your legacy code contains such unnecessary FP should make you rather wary of it's quality and the experience/expertise of it's developers.  However for the same source and target, the need for FP support will be the same, so, no floating-point is not in itself the reason for the large difference in size.

Rather than state that you are using "no optimisation", it would be better if you simply posted the compiler and linker switches applied.  In uVision at least there is a summary of all switches applied in the configuration dialog.  When ARM Compiler v6 is used uVision sets -O1 by default rather thean -O0, so you need to confirm that you have explicitly switched *off* optimisation rather than simply not switched it *on*.

It is of course not just a compiler issue. Keil's armlink does a thorough job of removing unreferenced code down to the function level.  I have not used GNU tools in a while, but it may well be linking all code in an object module even if only part of that module is actually used.

> Is there any way to resolve or investigate further?

What is there to resolve? The solution if the unoptimised code size is an issue is to use the more efficient toolchain.  MCUXpresso us free for commercial use, while ARM-MDK is *expensive*.  You get what you pay for in this case perhaps.

All that said, when comparing compiler performance it is more usual and fairer to compare optimisation. the are a few reasons to run unoptimised code:

1. When using a source level debugger, to maintain a 1 to 1 relationship between source lines and machine code, and to avoid removal of variables that you are watching/inspecting.
2. Poor quality legacy code that breaks when optimised due to undefined behaviour or failure to apply `volatile` where needed for example.
3. Code was debugged and developed unoptimised, and you have not thoroughly tested a build with optimisation applied.  If it meets deadlines, and fits the part unoptimised, the risk of behaviour change by optimisation might be better avoided until you have been able to thoroughly test it.

If your problem is that you need a good debug experience using the free toolchain, but the build does not fit the available ROM, then a solution to that is to selectively optimise the modules not being debugged.  It more simply switch optimisation on for all, then selectively switch it off for modules being debugged.  Hopefully your legacy code is not all in one module!  The more "modular" your code, the better this approach will work.  Though you do tend to have to rebuild rather often as your debug takes you into modules you may not have removed optimisation from.

---

From the question update (my ***highlight***):

> ARMCC compiler switches: -c --cpu Cortex-M3 -O0 ***-Otime*** --apcs=interwork --split_sections --asm --interleave --asm_dir ".\Output" -IC:/Keil_v5/ARM/RV31/INC -IC:/Keil_v5/ARM/CMSIS/Include -IC:/Keil_v5/ARM/INC/NXP/LPC177x_8x -D__UVISION_VERSION="537" -DDEBUG -DxxxLOG -o .\Output*.o --list_dir ".\Output" --list --omf_browse .\Output*.crf --depend .\Output*.d

While the compilers are very different and different code size might be expected, `-Otime` *is* an optimisation (you previously stated none were applied).  Even though the optimisation is aimed at minimising execution time and can in some cases increase code size by loop-unrolling for example, in general the techniques applied will result in *fewer* instructions this smaller code over a code base of any significant size.

From ARMCC manual:

> -Otime Performs optimizations to reduce execution time at the expense of a possible increase in image size.

Now there is an interaction between `-O`*n* and `-Otime` and `-Ospace` but it is not clearly stated in the manual whether -O0 entirely overrides `-Otime`. To be clear you should perhaps remove that for the purposes of comparison.

The presumed equivalent for gcc is `-Ofast` which implicitly enabled `-O3`, which if armcc were to do the same would easily account for the code size difference.

Furthermore the ARMCC/ARMLINK switches do not include debug information generation.  While that in itself has no impact on code size, it does suggest that the options are intended to be a "release build" (typically optimised this not conducive to debugging), while your GCC options are clearly aimed at a good debug experience - `-g3`, no optimisation.

The Thumb vs ARM issue is irrelevant, Cortex-M only supports the Thumb2 instruction set.  An attempt to execute 32-bit ARM code would result in a processor exception.

---

Now despite differences in optimisation, your ARMCC/ALRMLINK map has:

```
Program Size: Code=158,812 RO-data=195,200 RW-data=1,130,632 ZI-data=36424
```

But optimisation and toolchain will have little or no impact on RO-data, suggesting that of the GCC generated build's 829308 bytes, 620K is actual code.  It is hard to see how any optimisation could reduce that to 156K.

You have provided little information about the GCC build's link map, but my guess is that it is not removing unused code as agressively as ARMLINK can.  Note that the ARMLINK build uses `--info unused` - the map file will contain information about unused symbols that have been removed.  If you look in the GCC linkmap, you may find that that dead code is included in the MCUXpresso build.

Either way, the link-map is probably key to determining what is using space in the larger build, but not I think by looking at the summary data or blaming optimisation - that is likely a small part of the problem.  You need to compare the actual code linked or excluded.

On a more practical level, you might also reduce size by eliminating all floating point code.  If your code's use of floating point is all as naive as your `SEC_DELAY` macro/function, then eliminating it would be a vast improvement on both code size and execution speed.  There is no telling how well GNU's softfp performs compared to ARM's, but the difference may impact the real-time performance of your application.